# Update statement using Inner join in sql server using pyodbc in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

HI i am trying to update a table in sql server using pyodbc but i am not able to get the correct syntax.
Code snippet-

```
def fun(cur,tablename):

    cur.execute("""UPDATE sam
        SET
        sam.agreement_id = ?
        FROM '{0}' sam
        INNER JOIN dbo.agreement_mapping am ON sam.agreement_id = ?;
        """.format(tablename.replace('\'', '\'\'')),am.newagreementid,am.oldagreementid)
```

I am getting the error  `"name 'am' is not defined".
Is there any way i can perform this update query ?

Comment: The values for the placeholders need to be in a tuple or list: `(am.newagreementid,am.oldagreementid)`

Comment: @Barmar - Actually, that's not strictly true for pyodbc. As explained [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Features-beyond-the-DB-API#passing-parameters), `crsr.execute(stmt, paramval1, paramval2)` is supported.

Answer (score 1):

Refactoring your code for clarity,

```python
def fun(cur,tablename):

    cur.execute("""UPDATE sam
        SET
        sam.agreement_id = ?
        FROM '{0}' sam
        INNER JOIN dbo.agreement_mapping am ON sam.agreement_id = ?;
        """.format(tablename.replace('\'', '\'\'')),am.newagreementid,am.oldagreementid)
```

becomes

```python
def fun(cur,tablename):
    stmt = """\
        UPDATE sam
        SET
        sam.agreement_id = ?
        FROM '{0}' sam
        INNER JOIN dbo.agreement_mapping am ON sam.agreement_id = ?;
        """.format(tablename.replace('\'', '\'\''))
    cur.execute(stmt, am.newagreementid, am.oldagreementid)
```

There are two problems:

First, `'{0}'` wraps the table name in single quotes, turning it into a string literal. SQL Server table names are delimited by square brackets.

Second, the `am.newagreementid` and `am.oldagreementid` references in the `execute` call are evaluated in Python. Your Python code does not declare any Python variable or object named `am`, so those references are invalid.

So instead, you need to do something like this:

```python
def fun(cur,tablename):
    stmt = """\
        UPDATE sam
        SET
        sam.agreement_id = am.newagreementid
        FROM [{0}] sam
        INNER JOIN dbo.agreement_mapping am ON sam.agreement_id = am.oldagreementid;
        """.format(tablename.replace('\'', '\'\''))
    cur.execute(stmt)
```